# Should [copyleft] and [share-alike] be synonyms?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Both copyleft and share-alike have the same characteristics. Share-alike is obviously also the name of a CC license component.

Reading the tag wiki, it seems they refer to the same thing.

- Should they be synonyms?
- If so, should there by any other tags rolled in to it?
- What should be the 'primary' name?
- If not, how can we improve the tag wiki to differentiate between them?

Comment: This is [meta-tag:status-completed] :D It was a simple merge, all questions that had [tag:share-alike] already had the [tag:copyleft] tag anyway.

Comment: Hm... given that the GPL, one of the most prominent copyleft licenses, and CC-BY-SA, which has share-alike in its name, are incompatible, I find this to be an unfortunate merge.

Comment: @MichaelSchumacher can you give an example of a question (hypothetical or not) where it would matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Yes. The concept behind them is exactly the same. We already have [cc-by-sa](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cc-by-sa) for one of the licenses, we don't need a tag just for the clause.
- I haven't seen any, but I'm willing to add more in if they're suggested :)
- Probably [copyleft](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/copyleft). It's a broader tag, and encompasses [share-alike](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/share-alike). If they're this way round, we can simply merge the two, and [copyleft](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/copyleft) will still apply to the questions.
- N/A. I think the two should be synonymized.

(N.B. With a few more votes, if nobody objects, I'll merge the tags.)

Answer (score 5):

They aren't exactly the same terms, share-alike is broader. Copyleft includes the content to be free, while share-alike only demands sharing under the same terms, even if the term itself are non-free. best example are the two share-alike cc-licences. cc-by-sa is copyleft while cc-by-nc-sa is non-free and therefore not copyleft.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Share-alike vs. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyleft

How does this impact the tags? I don't know really. If Ziz says all uses of share-alike already had copyleft too, then share-alike is unneeded.

Comment: Copyleft isn't narrowly defined, so two people could differ in their opinion of whether cc nc-sa is copyleft or not (though not if it is free or not: it's not). This does make a reasonable case for having the synonym reversed though

Comment: @Martijn Ah heck, we can just update the tag wiki excerpt for that. :)